# Recommendations for reminder app

Tags: 22.04, software-recommendation, android, crossplatform

I'm looking for recommendations for a reminder app (I used ColorNote for that but I'd like to change). I'd like it to be cross platform (Android 13 and Ubuntu 22.04), and if possible to sync between devices.

The most important features for me would be the ability to set a reminder for an entire day, for a specific date and time, and recurring reminders (day, week, month). Pinning a reminder until further notice would be nice but not mandatory.

I looked at a few already, but if someone has better recommendations than what I've already seen, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can recommend GoTodo, which also has apps for most other platforms (android, iOS, Windows). They have a forever-free tier and the GUI is nice. I have not personally tried the Android version, but it is available on the Play-store.

https://gotodo.app/